# React, GraphQL: How to access render Result from Child in the Parent Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

Hope everyone is staying safe.

I'm sorry I could not find an answer online for my specific situation.

I have a `Child component` that `Queries` if the user is logged in and will return `true` or `false` (at least thats my expectation).

I want to capture this result in `Parent component` and display a `form` if true. But not sure how to do this: I'm getting the same output whether the use is logged in or not.

I have tried several configurations but didn't work. This is is my latest try.

***UPDATED Code as noted based on comment 1:***

But getting following errors:

**Error1:**

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`EditProfile`) while rendering a different component (`Query`). 
    in Query (at GetLoggedInUser
```

**Error2:**

```
Uncaught Error: Query(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.
    at reconcileChildFibers
```

**Parent Comp "EditProfile":**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Query, Mutation } from 'react-apollo';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import GetLoggedInUser from '../../../GetLoggedInUser'
// import { GetAuthUser } from './operations.graphql';

const EditProfile = ({match, location}) => {
  const reqUser = match.params.username;
  const prevUrl = location.pathname;
  const history = useHistory();
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  // const setLoginState = (e) => setIsLoggedIn(e)


  return (
    /*
    <GetLoggedInUser user={reqUser} props={setLoginState}>
      {console.log(`After query 'isLoggedIn' is: ${isLoggedIn}`)}
    </GetLoggedInUser>
    */

    // OLD Code
    // <GetLoggedInUser user={reqUser} /> ? "show form" : "don't show form" 
    //This where I'm having trouble I think?? "Show form" shows up either case.

   // ***NEW UPDATED***
   <GetLoggedInUser user={reqUser} setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn}/>
  )
}

export default EditProfile;
```

**Child (common) comp "GetLoggedInUser"**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { AuthUser } from './operations.graphql';

const GetLoggedInUser = ({user, setIsLoggedIn}) => {
  const reqUser = user;
  //const loggedIn = false;
  return  (
    <Query query={AuthUser}>
      {({loading, error, data}) => {
        if (loading) return <p><FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" size="lg" spin /></p>
        if (error)   return <p>{`Error: ${error}`}</p>

        const authUser = data.authUser.username;
        // OLD code
        // return ((authUser === reqUser) ? true : false)

        // ***NEW UPDATED***
        return setIsLoggedIn((authUser === reqUser) ? true : false)
      }}
    </Query>
  )
}

export default GetLoggedInUser;
```

**operations.graphql:** (this basically queries `context[:current_user]` and return it)

```
query AuthUser {
  authUser {
    id
    username
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: So I see you have commented out code `setIsLoggedIn`... why did you remove that? You were on the right path.

Comment: @wnamen thanks for the quick reply. I started on that path but got a warning; something like 'cannot update state while in Query or something'. Let me try again

Comment: Code updated per comment. But got errors